# Line-height property not working on tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

So basically, on [this tumblr theme that I'm working on](http://pastelharts.tumblr.com/), i'm trying to get the ask blocks to not space out that much.

See how in the ask boxes on the page, the spacing of the lines only for the question is much bigger than the rest of the text on the page? I've tried using the line-height property to no avail, and I've also tried fiddling with the font sizes. I'm not that experienced with code, so I was hoping maybe someone would see that I'm making some sort of really careless mistake that's so stupid I haven't thought to find it?

[Here's my code.](http://pastebin.com/8XqMQP9p)

The divs that I used for my ask are .ask-post, .question and .answer. I'm pretty sure they were also affected by other modifications I made, but I've yet to see any.. Anyway, yeah. Help, please! I'd really really appreciate it. <3

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Apart from the above, I doubt the 24 inclusions of `!important` are helping either. Ref: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are abusing `!important`.  You only use that when styles are applied at run-time, and even then, they should be avoided if possible.  You're breaking the hierarchical nature of CSS unnecessarily, and that's a big loss in modularity. It's like having a "goto" within a program.  You might as well have `style=...` on your HTML elements if you use `!important` all over the place.

Secondly, the `line-height` won't apply to the "question" div since you're using `display: inline` and the browser ignores issues with wrapped lines.  That works only within block elements.  So, you need to effect your left-to-right flow differently.

Suggestion:

- Remove `display: inline` and add `float: left` on `.asker`.
- Remove `display: inline` on `.question`.
- Add `overflow: hidden` on `.qa-post`.

`line-height` on `.question` should now work.

Comment: okay wait, actually, they're not on the same line anymore. line height is working but `float:left` isn't.  so i was wondering what the reason for that could be? and is using `style=...` on HTML bad? and sorry, i don't have enough reputation to do that. :\ once i do i'll come back and upvote you, though!

Comment: In your updated page, I didn't see `float: left` on `.question` but I was wrong anyway--  it belongs on `.asker` and should not be put on `.question`.  I edited the response above accordingly.

The reason `style=...` should be eschewed is because you're putting styling information right with the content.  That locks into you an appearance along with the content, which makes maintaining the site content and its appearance much more difficult.  Keep them separate, where possible.